# NES TV screen artifacts and game behavior changing due to old console/cartridge, what is physically happening?

Tags: nes, physical-media

Whenever my nephew comes to visit I grab my NES and we play some 30 year old games. Sometimes when I first power on the console the screen comes with artifacts, removing the cartridge and cleaning the slot and contacts make the game start running fine again.

Interestingly sometimes the problem is not only limited to the screen but sometimes it directly affects gameplay, specially in the game Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles 2 when I'm able to jump "under the screen" and can still hurt the enemies and they can't hurt me. Just to mention that this is not a pirated cartridge.

I only had the idea of making this question after some basic cleaning so I could not trigger the TMNT2 game problem, but Battle City can be seen having screen artifacts (that don't affect gameplay).

What could cause these issues in the games? Do the binary data from the cartridge to the console get corrupted and so the console use bad data to render the game? Can specific binary data be lost and change the game behavior? Is there no data consistency check done by the console over the data transferred?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is on-topic here, but you will probably a better answer at [Retro Computing](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I assume that what is happening is that the connection between the cart and the console isn't working as expected (the NES connectors had many documented design flaws), data is read incorrectly and you end up with the equivalent of Metroid "lost worlds" - the game uses whatever data it has even when the data is not fully valid. But BlueRaja is right, probably you would get a better answer on RetroComputing.

Comment: Was this the original NES, or the top-loading one? According to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/retrogaming/comments/2skjpx/nes_001_front_loadertoaster_vertical_line_problem/cnqkhj6/) this is caused by a flaw in the GPU of the top-loading model.  However they give no references, and no explanation for what the "flaw" is.